Scrollable screen divided into sections with badge navigation
Hey writing to ask if anyone may have seen or done a certain view and would like to share how to do it. I'm trying to make a scrollable screen divided into sections (each can have a different height). At the top of the screen I would like to have a horizontal list with the section titles (badge). The currently displayed section is supposed to be highlighted and clickable which scrolls to that section.  I tried to do this using scrollable_positioned_list it listens for the position and based on that I highlight the current visible one and scroll under the given index when I click. However, I have a problem when the sections are small and several are visible. When I click on the last badge, the screen scrolls to the bottom and the highlighted titles jump because I clicked on the last one but the screen still shows the earlier ones. I think this is a common screen but I cannot find  anywhere.


how many sections do you have? is it some fixed small number like 3,4 or 10, or you can have 1000s of them?

I would like to base this on builder because there may be a lot of sections (1000)
